# Div Class to Break Container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So Im using Bootstrap 4 alpha 3. Im using the container for my application. What Im trying to do is have the bottom section of my posts show page to have a different background color and I want that color to extend for the width of the entire page. I can't seem to find a way to break the container. Ive tried to follow some questions that were similar to this but they tend to have been from awhile back and the solutions don't seem to be working for Bootstrap 4. This is what Im trying right now

Inside my post show.html.erb

```
<div class="inner-container">
 ........
</div>
```

This is my post.scss

```
.inner-container {
 width: 100%;
 background: black;
 position: absolute;
}
```

The main background of my page is just a light grey. So again I just want to break the container just on this page and just for this Div class. I want the text and everything to stay in the container, Im just really trying to get the background color to extend the width of the entire page.

Comment: Can you give us a fiddle showing the problem? you've said what you tried, but not what it's doing or enough to recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
body {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Both BS alpha.3 and BS alpha.6 has this `body { margin: 0 }` not sure why it is not working for you. by default the `<body>` will have `margin: 8px` so you need to overwrite it.

```css
.inner-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
}


body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="inner-container">
  ........
</div>
```

Comment: It must be something in my code somewhere, because still getting the same thing.